# Is there a way to get a list of symlinks pointing somewhere under a partition?

Tags: ubuntu, symlink

I have a mounted partition with a lot of data on it, much of it is useless, but I want to backup what is still used. I know that everything that is still in use has a symlink pointing to it, for example: `/var/www -> /mnt/md1/var/www`.

I'd like to get a list of symlinks pointing to something under `/mnt/md1`.

Everything I find from my searches are about finding the symlinks pointing to a known destination, the difference here is that I don't know their destinations, only that they are somewhere under `/mnt/md1`

Maybe it would be easier if I unmount it and somehow find a list of broken symlinks?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`find`'s `-lname` predicate can be of use here:

```
find / -type l -lname '*/mnt/md1/*'
```

(the first asterisk is to find relative links that reach up to the root)

Comment: This could be the answer, unfortunately I had to cancel it after a few hours because it took too long, I've tried to play with -prune to ignore some directories, but it is still taking too long. I'll accept your answer as it probably does what I asked even if I couldn't test it.